# jQuery slideUp then slideDown on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a div to slide up when you pass your mouse over it, and then a different div to slide down.  This should be incredibly easy; I'm screwing up my syntax somewhere, though, and looking at examples, I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $( "#preCops" ).mouseover(function() {
      $( this ).slideUp();
      $( "#cops" ).slideDown();
   });
});
```

Comment: Could you make a demo..this is a little difficult without the HTML

Comment: This looks fine to me so I'll ask the easy questions first to get them out of the way: Is the jQuery library included on this page? If so, does your console in developer tools say "$ is not a function"?

Comment: I don't see any problems in your code: http://jsfiddle.net/jgnjy036/1/ It must be in your html or `slideDown` doesn't do what you think it should do. The element must be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking is the animations to run one after another but not at the same time.  The slideup has an complete hook so you can call you other slide to happen as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#preCops").mouseover(function() {
       $(this).slideUp(1000,  function(){ $("#cops").slideDown();});

   });
});
```